# C# p/invoke for GdipBitmapConvertFormat

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

How to convert this Gdi+ 1.1 signature to C# p/invoke?:

```
GpStatus WINGDIPAPI GdipBitmapConvertFormat(IN GpBitmap *pInputBitmap, 
PixelFormat format, DitherType dithertype, PaletteType palettetype, 
ColorPalette *palette, REAL alphaThresholdPercent);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536306(v=vs.85).aspx

What I have in this moment is:

```
internal static class GdiPlusWrapper
{
    [DllImport("gdiplus.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern Status GdipBitmapConvertFormat(HandleRef bitmap,
        PixelFormat format, DitherType dithertype, PaletteType palettetype,
        ColorPalette palette, float alpha);

    [DllImport("gdiplus.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern Status GdipInitializePalette(out ColorPalette pallete,
        PaletteType palettetype, int optimalColors, bool useTransparentColor,
        HandleRef bitmap);

    internal enum DitherType
    {
        DitherTypeNone = 0,
        DitherTypeSolid = 1,
        DitherTypeOrdered4x4 = 2,
        DitherTypeOrdered8x8 = 3,
        DitherTypeOrdered16x16 = 4,
        DitherTypeOrdered91x91 = 5,
        DitherTypeSpiral4x4 = 6,
        DitherTypeSpiral8x8 = 7,
        DitherTypeDualSpiral4x4 = 8,
        DitherTypeDualSpiral8x8 = 9,
        DitherTypeErrorDiffusion = 10,
    }

    internal enum PaletteType
    {
        PaletteTypeCustom = 0,
        PaletteTypeOptimal = 1,
        PaletteTypeFixedBW = 2,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone8 = 3,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone27 = 4,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone64 = 5,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone125 = 6,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone216 = 7,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone252 = 8,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone256 = 9
    }

    internal enum Status
    {
        Ok = 0,
        GenericError = 1,
        InvalidParameter = 2,
        OutOfMemory = 3,
        ObjectBusy = 4,
        InsufficientBuffer = 5,
        NotImplemented = 6,
        Win32Error = 7,
        WrongState = 8,
        Aborted = 9,
        FileNotFound = 10,
        ValueOverflow = 11,
        AccessDenied = 12,
        UnknownImageFormat = 13,
        FontFamilyNotFound = 14,
        FontStyleNotFound = 15,
        NotTrueTypeFont = 16,
        UnsupportedGdiplusVersion = 17,
        GdiplusNotInitialized = 18,
        PropertyNotFound = 19,
        PropertyNotSupported = 20,
        ProfileNotFound = 21
    }

    internal static T GetPrivateField<T>(this object obj, string fieldName)
    {
        if (obj == null) return default(T);

        var ltType = obj.GetType();
        var lfiFieldInfo = ltType.GetField(fieldName,
            BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        if (lfiFieldInfo != null)
            return (T) lfiFieldInfo.GetValue(obj);
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            String.Format("Instance field '{0}' could not be located in object of type '{1}'.", fieldName,
                obj.GetType().FullName));
    }
}
```

And this is how you use this:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(@"testing\image.png");
var bmpHandle = new HandleRef(bitmap, bitmap.GetPrivateField<IntPtr>("nativeImage"));
ColorPalette palette = null;

GdiPlusWrapper.GdipInitializePalette(out palette, GdiPlusWrapper.PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal, 0,
    true, bmpHandle);

foreach (GdiPlusWrapper.DitherType dither in Enum.GetValues(typeof(GdiPlusWrapper.DitherType)))
{

    GdiPlusWrapper.GdipBitmapConvertFormat(bmpHandle, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555,
       dither, GdiPlusWrapper.PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedBW, ref palette, 0.0f);
    bitmap.Save(@"testing\image_" + dither + ".png");
}
```

But the dithering isn't working :(

The pallete generation seems to be the issue. Any hint?

Comment: What is wrong with `Bitmap.ConvertFormat`? And can you describe what "isn't working" means. Why did you use `SetLastError = true`?

Comment: Well, basically is returning the normal plain PixelFormat conversion http://cl.ly/TJIw not a dithered one. SetLastError was left only because I copied similar sentences from p/invoke but I am not thinking to handle errors yet.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan One reason to not use **Bitmap.ConvertFormat** is that [there is no **Bitmap.ConvertFormat**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap) (it never made it into the .NET translation of GDI+; hence why he is trying to P/Invoke it)

Comment: @Ian er, yeah, that seems like a very good reason!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution in http://download.csdn.net/download/laviewpbt/4900954

```
// Source: http://download.csdn.net/download/laviewpbt/4900954
// Author: http://download.csdn.net/user/laviewpbt

namespace PrimeLib
{
    public enum DitherType
    {
        DitherTypeNone = 0,
        DitherTypeSolid = 1,
        DitherTypeOrdered4x4 = 2,
        DitherTypeOrdered8x8 = 3,
        DitherTypeOrdered16x16 = 4,
        DitherTypeSpiral4x4 = 5,
        DitherTypeSpiral8x8 = 6,
        DitherTypeDualSpiral4x4 = 7,
        DitherTypeDualSpiral8x8 = 8,
        DitherTypeErrorDiffusion = 9,
        DitherTypeMax = 10
    }
    public enum PaletteType
    {
        PaletteTypeCustom = 0,
        PaletteTypeOptimal = 1,
        PaletteTypeFixedBW = 2,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone8 = 3,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone27 = 4,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone64 = 5,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone125 = 6,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone216 = 7,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone252 = 8,
        PaletteTypeFixedHalftone256 = 9
    }

    public static class GdipEffect
    {
        [DllImport("gdiplus.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GdipInitializePalette(ref GdiPalette Pal, int palettetype, int optimalColors,
            int useTransparentColor, IntPtr bitmap);

        [DllImport("gdiplus.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GdipInitializePalette(int[] Pal, PaletteType palettetype, int optimalColors,
            int useTransparentColor, IntPtr bitmap);

        [DllImport("gdiplus.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GdipBitmapConvertFormat(IntPtr bitmap, int pixelFormat, DitherType dithertype,
            PaletteType palettetype, ref GdiPalette Pal, float alphaThresholdPercent);

        [DllImport("gdiplus.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GdipBitmapConvertFormat(IntPtr bitmap, int pixelFormat, DitherType dithertype,
            PaletteType palettetype, int[] Pal, float alphaThresholdPercent);

        [DllImport("gdiplus.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GdipBitmapConvertFormat(IntPtr bitmap, int pixelFormat, DitherType dithertype,
            PaletteType palettetype, IntPtr Pal, float alphaThresholdPercent);

        public static void ChangeTo8bppIndexed(this Bitmap Bmp, PaletteType palettetype = PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal,
            DitherType ditherType = DitherType.DitherTypeErrorDiffusion, int optimalColors = 256)
        {
            int Entries;
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534159(v=vs.85).aspx
            switch (palettetype)
            {
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedBW:
                    Entries = 2;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone8:
                    Entries = 16;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone27:
                    Entries = 36;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone64:
                    Entries = 73;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone125:
                    Entries = 134;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone216:
                    Entries = 225;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone252:
                    Entries = 253;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone256:
                    Entries = 256;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal:
                    if (optimalColors <= 0 || optimalColors > 256)
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                            "Colors should be between 0 (inclusive) and 256 (exclusive)");
                    Entries = optimalColors;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Error");
            }
            var Pal = new int[2 + Entries];
            Pal[0] = (int) PaletteFlags.GrayScale; // Flag
            Pal[1] = Entries; // Count
            if (palettetype == PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal)
                GdipInitializePalette(Pal, palettetype, Entries, 0, Bmp.NativeHandle());
            else
                GdipInitializePalette(Pal, palettetype, Entries, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (palettetype == PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal)
                if (ditherType != DitherType.DitherTypeNone && ditherType != DitherType.DitherTypeSolid &&
                    ditherType != DitherType.DitherTypeErrorDiffusion)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Arguments error");
            GdipBitmapConvertFormat(Bmp.NativeHandle(), Convert.ToInt32(PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed), ditherType,
                palettetype, Pal, 50f);
        }

        public static void ChangeToSpecialIndexed(this Bitmap Bmp, PaletteType palettetype = PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal,
           DitherType ditherType = DitherType.DitherTypeErrorDiffusion, int optimalColors = 256)
        {
            int Entries;
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534159(v=vs.85).aspx
            switch (palettetype)
            {
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedBW:
                    Entries = 2;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone8:
                    Entries = 16;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone27:
                    Entries = 36;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone64:
                    Entries = 73;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone125:
                    Entries = 134;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone216:
                    Entries = 225;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone252:
                    Entries = 253;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone256:
                    Entries = 256;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal:
                    if (optimalColors <= 0 || optimalColors > 256)
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                            "Colors should be between 0 (inclusive) and 256 (exclusive)");
                    Entries = optimalColors;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Error");
            }
            var Pal = new int[2 + Entries];
            Pal[0] = (int)PaletteFlags.GrayScale; // Flag
            Pal[1] = Entries; // Count
            if (palettetype == PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal)
                GdipInitializePalette(Pal, palettetype, Entries, 0, Bmp.NativeHandle());
            else
                GdipInitializePalette(Pal, palettetype, Entries, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (palettetype == PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal)
                if (ditherType != DitherType.DitherTypeNone && ditherType != DitherType.DitherTypeSolid &&
                    ditherType != DitherType.DitherTypeErrorDiffusion)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Arguments error");
            GdipBitmapConvertFormat(Bmp.NativeHandle(), Convert.ToInt32(PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555), ditherType,
                palettetype, Pal, 50f);
        }

        public static void ChangeTo4bppIndexed(this Bitmap Bmp, PaletteType palettetype = PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal,
            DitherType ditherType = DitherType.DitherTypeErrorDiffusion, int optimalColors = 16)
        {
            int Entries;
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534159(v=vs.85).aspx
            switch (palettetype)
            {
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedBW:
                    Entries = 2;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedHalftone8:
                    Entries = 16;
                    break;
                case PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal:
                    if (optimalColors <= 0 || optimalColors > 16)
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Colors should be between 0 (inclusive) and 16 (exclusive)");
                    Entries = optimalColors;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Error");
            }
            var Pal = new int[2 + Entries];
            Pal[0] = (int) PaletteFlags.GrayScale; // Flag
            Pal[1] = Entries; // Count
            if (palettetype == PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal)
                GdipInitializePalette(Pal, palettetype, Entries, 0, Bmp.NativeHandle());
            else
                GdipInitializePalette(Pal, palettetype, Entries, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (palettetype == PaletteType.PaletteTypeOptimal)
                if (ditherType != DitherType.DitherTypeNone && ditherType != DitherType.DitherTypeSolid &&
                    ditherType != DitherType.DitherTypeErrorDiffusion)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Arguments error");
            GdipBitmapConvertFormat(Bmp.NativeHandle(), Convert.ToInt32(PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed), ditherType,
                palettetype, Pal, 50f);
        }

        public static void ChangeTo1bppIndexed(this Bitmap Bmp,
            DitherType ditherType = DitherType.DitherTypeErrorDiffusion)
        {
            if (ditherType != DitherType.DitherTypeSolid && ditherType != DitherType.DitherTypeErrorDiffusion)
                throw new ArgumentException("Arguments error.");
            var Pal = new int[4];
            Pal[0] = (int) PaletteFlags.GrayScale; // Flag
            Pal[1] = 2; // Count
            GdipInitializePalette(Pal, PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedBW, 2, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            GdipBitmapConvertFormat(Bmp.NativeHandle(), Convert.ToInt32(PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed), ditherType,
                PaletteType.PaletteTypeFixedBW, Pal, 50f);
        }

        public static void ChangeTo16bppRgb555(this Bitmap Bmp,
            DitherType ditherType = DitherType.DitherTypeErrorDiffusion)
        {
            GdipBitmapConvertFormat(Bmp.NativeHandle(), Convert.ToInt32(PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555), ditherType,
                PaletteType.PaletteTypeCustom, IntPtr.Zero, 50f);
        }

        public static void ChangeTo24bppRgb(this Bitmap Bmp)
        {
            GdipBitmapConvertFormat(Bmp.NativeHandle(), Convert.ToInt32(PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb),
                DitherType.DitherTypeNone, PaletteType.PaletteTypeCustom, IntPtr.Zero, 50f);
        }

        public static void ChangeTo32bppARGB(this Bitmap Bmp)
        {
            GdipBitmapConvertFormat(Bmp.NativeHandle(), Convert.ToInt32(PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb),
                DitherType.DitherTypeNone, PaletteType.PaletteTypeCustom, IntPtr.Zero, 50f);
        }

        internal static TResult GetPrivateField<TResult>(this object obj, string fieldName)
        {
            if (obj == null) return default(TResult);
            Type ltType = obj.GetType();
            FieldInfo lfiFieldInfo = ltType.GetField(fieldName,
                BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (lfiFieldInfo != null)
                return (TResult) lfiFieldInfo.GetValue(obj);
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                string.Format("Instance field '{0}' could not be located in object of type '{1}'.", fieldName,
                    obj.GetType().FullName));
        }

        public static IntPtr NativeHandle(this Bitmap Bmp)
        {
            return Bmp.GetPrivateField<IntPtr>("nativeImage");
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct GdiPalette
        {
            internal readonly PaletteFlags Flag;
            internal readonly int Count;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1024)] internal readonly byte[] Entries;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the cleaned file (basically just removing Chinese chars):
https://github.com/eried/PrimeComm/blob/7cbce9f16a0f647c43a6b69e7a77a820a0f80df4/PrimeLib/GdipEffect.cs

I was pretty near, but it seems the palette isn't defined for non-indexed pixelformats. I am not sure if this is 100% correct, but at least it kinda works (images still present 'banding' effects).

Comment: Code was added to the answer

Comment: We are all losing time just by breathing, but the issue is now solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the two functions that are meant to match:

**C++**

```
GpStatus WINGDIPAPI GdipBitmapConvertFormat(IN GpBitmap *pInputBitmap, 
    PixelFormat format, DitherType dithertype, PaletteType palettetype, 
    ColorPalette *palette, REAL alphaThresholdPercent);
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport("gdiplus.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, 
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GdipBitmapConvertFormat(HandleRef bitmap, 
    PixelFormat format, DitherType dithertype, ref ColorPalette palette, 
    float alpha);
```

It is immediately apparent that your functions have different parameter lists. The parameter counts do not match. The C+ has 6 parameters, the C++ has 5 parameters. You have missed the `PaletteType` parameter.

On top of that your handling of `ColorPalette` is wrong. This is a variable sized struct. The color array has variable length. You don't appear to cater for that. And you have declared it as a class rather than a struct. Which means that your use of `out` and `ref` on the `ColorPalette` parameters results in an erroneous extra level of indirection.

In any case, you'll need to perform some custom marshalling for this type. Not the easiest task, and not one that I particularly want to get in to in this answer. It is going to involve manual memory allocation and struct marshalling.

A less important error is your use of `SetLastError`. These functions do not set the Win32 last error value. You should remove that part of your attribute.

Error checking is important though. You are not doing it. You do need to check the return value of these GDI+ functions. I am quite sure that the call to `GdipInitializePalette` will return a value indicating failure, for the reason discussed above.

Comment: Hi, wow! I totally missed that part about the arguments. Thanks I will fix that and test again. I am using this because the conversion does not apply dithering (I asked the other question looking for a solution, and this is one of the solutions I think it might work)

Comment: Ha! I can't believe that I did not spot that you had asked that other question! I've removed that part of my answer and will not cast judgement on whether or not using pinvoke is the right approach here.

Comment: Now, you'll need to fix more than just the missing argument. You won't get anywhere without fixing ColorPalette. I think you are going to need to do that with a call to `AllocCoTaskMem` or `AllocHGlobal`, and manual marshalling of the fields with `Marshal` class to copy fields around. And the array of colours. You cannot get the p/invoke marshaller to deal with a variable sized struct.

Comment: Thanks David, I already fixed it and it is returning "GenericError" so for sure the first problem is in the palette.

Comment: `GdiPlusWrapper.GdipInitializePalette` (probably because the thing you said about fixing ColorPalette but I can't find any info about this so I am just trying things). `GdiPlusWrapper.GdipBitmapConvertFormat` returns OK, but without a valid palette it is just doing a non-dithered conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to point out a huge gotcha not mentioned in the documentation.

When you call **GdipInitializePalette**:

- you tell it you want it to create an optimal palette of 256 colors
- and pass it a pointer to a buffer that is large enough to hold the `ColorPalette` header, and 256 DWORD color values to follow.

```
struct ColorPalette 
{
   UInt32 flags;
   UInt32 count;
   UInt32[256] entries;
}
ColorPalette palette;

GdipInitializePalette(palette, PaletteTypeOptimal, 256, False, bitmap);
```

The idea is that **GdipInitializePalette** will populate the `ColorPalette` buffer for you.

Except that isn't completely true. Even though you specified `256` colors in the palette, you also need to specify `palette.count = 256`:

```
ColorPalette palette;
palette.count = 256; //must tell it twice that you want 256 colors
GdipInitializePalette(palette, PaletteTypeOptimal, 256, False, bitmap);
```